# Ставится ли тире после слова "эта"?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

*Эта книга (—) моя, а эта (—) твоя.*

Здесь тире может быть факультативным или в любом случае в нём нет необходимости?

Comment: Второе нужно из-за пропущенного слова.

Comment: @oleedd нет, там оно тоже факультативно: "При отсутствии паузы в месте пропуска члена предложения тире не ставится: Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку (Ч.);…Ты делаешь вещи долгие, а я короткие (Леон.)" (Розенталь, § 6.5).

Comment: @Nektoid Да, но здесь желательно. Нужно не значит обязательно.

Comment: @oleedd вы всерьёз? Разумеется, "нужно" значит "обязательно". "Нужно" — это когда есть чёткое и однозначное правило. Все остальные случаи — это "допустимо", "желательно" и т. п.

Comment: @Nektoid Да ладно. Если нужно купить хлеб, то это не значит, что обязательно надо идти и покупать. Бывает, что нужно, но можно обойтись без этого.

Comment: @oleedd ясно-понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно, нужно только второе тире потому, что подразумевается слово *книга* и во второй части. Смотрите у [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93#pp93) (§ 6, п. 5):

> Тире ставится в неполном предложении, составляющем **часть сложного предложения,** когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое) восстанавливается из предыдущей части фразы и в месте пропуска делается **пауза:** *Ермолай стрелял, как всегда, победоносно; я — довольно плохо* (Т.)

Примеры не продолжил, многоточие не очень смотрится в конце.

И как верно говорят комментирующие, без паузы и тире не нужно, но я бы сделал тут паузу, так лучше звучит.

Comment: Вполне возможен вариант с двумя тире, если подчёркивается параллелизм конструкций.

Comment: Может быть. Только не приходят в голову такие примеры.